# Spring Boot application connect with Docker mysql server user

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application, and when I connect it to my local mysql server it runs perfectly fine.

Now, I am trying to connect it to the docker mysql server. But I am always getting this error :

`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'arqam'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)`

BUT IT CONNECTS WITH THE ROOT USER OF DOCKER MYSQL PERFECTLY.

**Spring boot resource file** :

```
spring:
datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/test_db?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: arqam
    password: root
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

**Docker part**

- When I run `sudo docker inspect imageId` :

  "Ports": {
              "3306/tcp": [
                  {
                      "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                      "HostPort": "3310"
                  }
              ],
              "33060/tcp": null
          },
          "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
          "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
  }

Running `docker ps` :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
3c7sj342938        mysql:8             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 months ago        Up About an hour    33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3310->3306/tcp   mysqlContainer
```

I haven't posted other data, if anything else is needed will post that also.
I went through [this post](https://code.scottshipp.com/2019/06/13/connect-a-spring-boot-app-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container/), and made my d`datasource url` as mentioned, but its not connecting to the mysql server.

So, how can I connect my user to spring boot application. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: can you share output of command `docker ps` ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I added the output

Comment: port which is listening 3310 of mysql DB , you should change to `jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3310/`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan That doesn't work. I am exposing 3310, but the docker mysql is hosted on 3306.
https://code.scottshipp.com/2019/06/13/connect-a-spring-boot-app-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container/?unapproved=341&moderation-hash=ccd6d80911e97490e655e95bcda4ff22#comment-341

Comment: you exposed 3310 so your spring boot have to connect 3310 port, what is error output ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan When I put 3310, it doesn't connect. Says connection failed. With 3306 it is able to connect with root users, just that user other than root it is not able to connect.

Comment: I know this is an unlikely solution but you have to start somewhere. Did you create the user arqam in the Docker MySql instance? Are you able to log in with that user from the CLI?

Comment: @ScottShipp Yes to both of your question. What I think most probably is that arqam user has overriden the root user. Is that possible>?

Comment: @arqam Perhaps check out https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ and make sure you have issued the "GRANT ALL" command mentioned there under "Create the database" for the arqam user?

Comment: @ScottShipp I have give the Grant All permission to the arqam user. The strange thing happening is in the docker terminal, I cannot login the root user but I can login the arqam user.
Whereas in springboot for the same mysql server connection the opposite works.

Comment: @arqam that makes no sense, it sounds like maybe you have two mysql instances running, perhaps two Docker-contained instances or one non-Docker container and one in a Docker container. It will be necessary for you to check all processes that are running on both your host and via docker ps command and determine how to get back to just having one running